# Promise.defer() browser support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, promise, es6-promise

I am looking for a way to create deferred object which will be resolved outside the current scope. I like deferred objects and as I see `Promise.defer()` in Chrome 38 returns the deferred object.

But in latest Firefox 34 `Promise.defer` is undefined as well in Safari 8.0.

So I can't use `Promise.defer` everywhere now. What about future status? Will it be implemented in other browsers or will be removed as deprecated?

Comment: Well you can create custom deferred object using Promise if you really want to.

Comment: It is scheduled to be removed from Chrome as well as `chain`.

Comment: Promise.defer() has stopped working for me in Google Chrome. (Version 52.0.2743.82)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [the MDN article on Deferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred), the `.defer` method is obsolete. If you look at [this bug issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1034599), it says that `Promise.defer` is non-standard, so it's not likely to return.

> Starting from Gecko 30, this object is obsolete and should not be used anymore. Use the `new Promise()` constructor instead.

They offer an example of how to rewrite `Promise.defer` code, to instead use `new Promise`.

### Promise.defer

```
var deferred = Promise.defer();
doSomething(function cb(good) {
    if (good)
        deferred.resolve();
    else
        deferred.reject();
});
return deferred.promise;
```

### new Promise

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    doSomething(function cb(good) {
        if (good)
            resolve();
        else
            reject();
    });
});
```

There are several advantages to the new format, including cleaner code, and improved throw safety (if the code in the promise init function throws synchronously the promise will reject).

Comment: It's worth mentioning _why_ it was removed - the promise constructor is throw safe unlike the deferred. If you throw in the scope of the promise constructor it will convert it to a rejection for you.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, thanks, that's really what I mean.

Comment: more complete why: [Difference between defer().promise and Promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28687566/1048572)

Comment: However the ability to resolve or reject a promise (deferred) at a distance, óutside the constructor, is lost.

Comment: So when promise needs to be resolved/rejected outside of the constructor, what do we do now? dfsq's answer?

Comment: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/deferred-migration.html

Answer (score 35):

Although I doubt this is a good idea, but technically you can implement custom deferred object based on Promises. For example:

```js
function defer() {
    var deferred = {};
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        deferred.resolve = resolve;
        deferred.reject  = reject;
    });
    deferred.promise = promise;
    return deferred;
}

var deferred = defer();

deferred.promise.then(function(data) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Resolved: ' + data + '</p>';
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<p>Deferred created.</p>';

setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve(123);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: this is considered a Promise anti-pattern because it doesn't allow for correct propagation of errors

Comment: @Alnitak I know it, that's why I said it's not a good idea. I just demonstrated that it's technically possible to implement deferred object.

Comment: @Alnitak it has nothing to do with propagation of errors - you're mistaking the deferred anti pattern with constructing a promise with a deferred.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum And since you are here, it would be really interesting, how you would answer OP question? Because my solution feels awkward.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum oops, misremembered what the problem was

Comment: @dfsq I upvoted your solution for being pragmatic and the solution provided by Alexander O'Mara is correct. I'm not sure what I can further add here.

Comment: Thanks for answers! But when I know the risk about uncaught exceptions, can I extract deferred like shown there?

Comment: @just-boris yes - the promise constructor is _guaranteed_ to run the code passed to it synchronously so the above approach is guaranteed to work successfully. Extracting a deferred was one of the main considerations when the constraint of running it synchronously was placed. This is guaranteed to work in every browser and in every library implementing the promise constructor specification.

Comment: For future readers pondering on this issue. The mentioned Promise anti-pattern related to uncaught exceptions. It happens when the initiating callback function throws an exception and it should go to the reject handler but it doesn't. More info at http://bytearcher.com/articles/pitfalls-of-promisifying-by-band/

Comment: This helps me.I'm asked to use a sharepoint package,encounter a case where the call function is executeQueryAsync,succeeded and fail response are in two separated function.I got to use deferred to set succeeded and fail response one by one.

Comment: This is great for unit testing state when promises are in flight.  Like checking if that button is disabled while waiting for the promise to return.

Comment: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/deferred-migration.html

Answer (score 3):

Promise.withResolvers() has been added to the spec. See [this MDM article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/withResolvers)

It can be used like this:

> ```
> async function* readableToAsyncIterable(stream) {
>   let { promise, resolve, reject } = Promise.withResolvers();
>   stream.on("error", (error) => reject(error));
>   stream.on("end", () => resolve());
>   stream.on("readable", () => resolve());
>
>   while (stream.readable) {
>     await promise;
>     let chunk;
>     while ((chunk = stream.read())) {
>       yield chunk;
>     }
>     ({ promise, resolve, reject } = Promise.withResolvers());
>   }
> }
> ```