# Javascript completable future?

Tags: javascript, promise, future

I'm looking at both [PromiseJS](https://www.promisejs.org/) and [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for something similar to a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), but couldn't find any.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved in javascript?  Thanks

Note: `Promise.resolve()` isn't suitable, unless you can create the `Promise` object first and complete it later.

**Update**

As all answers pointed out, the correct way is to use `Promise`'s constructor:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(data); })
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create `Promise` object, then resolve at future point. Can you include `javascript` tried at Question? Describe expected result?

Comment: Please show us the code that you would like to write and we can tell you how to do it correctly. As it stands, it really isn't a very specific question.

Comment: Here's how you make a deferred object using ES6 standard promises (if that's what you're trying to do): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651780/why-does-the-promise-constructor-need-an-executor/37673534#37673534

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note: Promise.resolve() isn't suitable, unless you can create the
>   Promise object first and complete it later.

You can use `Promise` constructor, pass `onFulfilled`, `onRejected` arguments outside scope of `executor` function

```js
var complete, err, now = new Date().getTime();

var promise = new Promise((onFulfilled, onRejected) => {
  complete = onFulfilled; err = onRejected;
});

promise.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});

setTimeout(() => {
  complete("promise resolved " 
           + (new Date().getTime() - now) 
           + " in the future")
}, Math.random() * 3500)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no deferred-like API in JavaScript [for good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28687566/1048572). You don't have a `CompletableFuture` with a `.complete` method, instead you just use the [`new Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You already linked [some documentation](https://www.promisejs.org/#construction) containing examples so I'm not going to repeat them here.

Answer (score 0):

Just meet the same need, this is how I do this in TypeScript

```
export function createLazyPromise<T = any>(): Promise<T> & { reject: () => void, resolve: (v: T) => void } {
  let onResolve, onReject;
  const promise = new Promise<T>(((resolve, reject) => {
    onResolve = resolve;
    onReject = reject
  }));
  promise['resolve'] = onResolve;
  promise['reject'] = onReject;
  return promise as any
}
```

Usee like this

```
test('test shell', async () => {
  // resolve later
  const promise = createLazyPromise();
  const result = shell.exec(
    'ps aux | head -3',
    {
      silent: true,
    },
    (code, stdout, stderr) => {
      promise.resolve({code, stdout, stderr});
    }
  );

  console.log(result.pid);

  console.log(await promise);
});
```