# Deferred that extends Promise

Tags: typescript, promise, deferred

How to implement a Deferred promise that extends Promise? It's important to extend Promise for type-safe usage where a typical Promise is expected.

Following implementation

```
export class Deferred<T> extends Promise<T> {                                   
  public _resolveSelf;
  public _rejectSelf;                                                           
  constructor() {
    super(
      (resolve, reject) =>
      {
        this._resolveSelf = resolve
        this._rejectSelf = reject
      }
    )
  }                                                                             
  public resolve(val:T) { this._resolveSelf(val) }
  public reject(reason:any) { this._rejectSelf(reason) }                        
}
```

throws `TypeError: _this is undefined`.

In [this Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Deferred%3CT%3E%20extends%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20public%20_resolveSelf%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20_rejectSelf%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._resolveSelf%20%3D%20resolve%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._rejectSelf%20%3D%20reject%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20public%20resolve(val%3AT)%20%7B%20this._resolveSelf(val)%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20public%20reject(reason%3Aany)%20%7B%20this._rejectSelf(reason)%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20d%20%3D%20new%20Deferred%0D%0A%0D%0Ad.then(console.log)%0D%0A%0D%0Ad.resolve(10)), one can see that the compiled javascript is funny. In line 15, during declaration of `_this` already its properties are being assigned.

Comment: It's enough to implement `PromiseLike` in order to have a type that is compatible with type `Promise`

Comment: The problem is you can't use `this` before the `super()` call.

Comment: Took me a while to find it, here's the [`PromiseLike` interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a3f39ece62aae1dc6e358f8fafa652c80c162379/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1255).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
export class Deferred<T> implements Promise<T> {

  private _resolveSelf;
  private _rejectSelf;
  private promise: Promise<T>

  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>
      {
        this._resolveSelf = resolve
        this._rejectSelf = reject

      }
    )
  }

  public then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
    onfulfilled?: ((value: T) =>
      TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
    onrejected?: ((reason: any) =>
      TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null
    ): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2> {
      return this.promise.then(onfulfilled, onrejected)
    }

  public catch<TResult = never>(
    onrejected?: ((reason: any) =>
      TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null
    ): Promise<T | TResult> {
      return this.promise.catch(onrejected)
    }

  public resolve(val:T) { this._resolveSelf(val) }
  public reject(reason:any) { this._rejectSelf(reason) }

  [Symbol.toStringTag]: 'Promise'

}
```

Method signatures of `then` and `catch` copy-pasted from [Typescript's Promise interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1336) and cosmetically cleaned up. The `[Symbol.toStringTag]` line is also necessary for Typescript to consider this a Promise, though you only find that out at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

> How to implement a Deferred promise that extends Promise?

Better not at all. There is absolutely [no good reason to use deferreds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692824/1048572).

And even then, a deferred that *is a* promise is a bad idea, you should separate the capabilities:

```
function defer() {
    var deferred = {};
    deferred.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        deferred.resolve = resolve;
    });
    return deferred;
}
```

> One can see that the compiled javascript is funny. In line 15, during declaration of _this already its properties are being assigned.

Yes, that's how `super` works: you cannot use `this` until the parent constructor call returned and intitialised it. The promise executor callback gets called before that however.

You'd have to write

```
export class Deferred<T> extends Promise<T> {
  public resolve: T=>void;
  public reject: any=>void;
  constructor() {
    var resolveSelf, rejectSelf
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      resolveSelf = resolve
      _rejectSelf = reject
    })
    this.resolve = resolveSelf;
    this.reject = rejectSelf;
  }
}
```

Comment: Deferred decouples promise declaration and resolution (rejection). Surely you can think of situations where that's useful. 95% of the time, promises are preferable. They are simpler and are a better general tool, that's what the question you linked to explains. That doesn't imply they don't have their uses.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis Even for most of the other 5%, the decoupled `resolve` function - which can be stored and passed around as well - is already enough. Needing both the resolver and the promise in the same data structure (like my `defer()`) is really really rare. Maybe even so rare that a dedicated helper function isn't worth it.

Comment: Totally agree with @DominykasMostauskis here. The article you link to Bergi doesn't even say there is no good reason to use deferreds you just made that part up.

Comment: @JohnCulviner Ok, maybe I should've phrased it differently. The answer I linked gives "*a good reason not to use deferreds*". That there also are no good reasons to use them is indeed my opinion. Coupling the promise and its resolution capability into a single object should be avoided. Every code that uses deferred can be written just as easily/concisely with the `Promise` constructor.