# Chrome defines a method on Promise "defer", but this is not in the spec - is this non-standard?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Chrome defines a method on Promise "defer", but this is not in the spec - is this non-standard?

In Chrome:

```
typeof Promise.defer === 'function' // true
```

But I cannot see anything in the ES2015 spec mentioning this API. Presumably this is vestigial?

Chrome version: 51.0.2704.103 m

Comment: Which versions of chrome have you tried `javascript` at Question at?

Comment: Seems to be [non-standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889687/promise-defer-browser-support). Why was it removed? _It's worth mentioning why it was removed - the promise constructor is throw safe unlike the deferred. If you throw in the scope of the promise constructor it will convert it to a rejection for you._

Comment: If it's not in the spec, then it is non-standard, yes. (It's in none of the other standards either, if that is what you mean)

Comment: @Bergi "It's in none of the other standards" - please can you clarify?

Comment: You asked whether it is in any standard, I said that it is in none. (There are more standards than the ES2015 spec)

Comment: Ah so 3, 5.1, 6 (2015), 7 (2016) etc